# How i can i revert the comands i made on ubuntu terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, permissions, chmod, usergroups

I made a mistake and ran the command below on my root directory, now my system is all messed up. I can't run Sudo, etc. Is there any way I can revert this command, or set back the correct user permissions?

```
sudo chmod -R 777
```

Comment: I don't think so, because you'd have to know the permissions of each file before the change.

Comment: men...i'm doomed!